# Duda en el análisis sintáctico de una oración

Tags: sintaxis, subordinadas

En la presente oración "Será siquiera verdad **que el tamaño del cerebro se relacione con la inteligencia**", la parte de la oración subrayada qué función realiza. Las opciones son:

1. una subordinada adjetiva de complemento atributo.
2. una subordinada sustantiva de sujeto.
3. una subordinada sustantiva de complemento directo.
4. una subordinada adjetiva de complemento del nombre.

Argumento la que creo que es la respuesta correcta y las dudas que me surgen.

1. Para ser correcta debería coger el término "verdad" ya que considero que éste realiza la función de Atributo al ser una oración con verbo copulativo (ser).
2. Ahí se me presentan algunas dudas ya que podríamos seleccionar como sujeto "el tamaño" y teniendo en cuenta que "siquiera" es una conjunción, la oración podría quedar así: Aunque sea verdad el tamaño o aunque los tamaños no sean verdad.
3. Queda descartada porque no puede haber un CD en una oración con verbo copulativo (debería ser el Atributo).
4. También me presenta dudas porque "verdad" es un sustantivo y si la parte subrayada la substituimos por "indiscutible", la oración quedaría: Será siquiera una verdad indiscutible realizando la función de complemento del nombre.

Agradecería intercambio de información, pues me interesa saber la respuesta y su justificación para aprender. Un cordial saludo.

Answer (score 2):

El uso de "siquiera" es raro en esa oración. Uno tendería a usar otra palabra, como "acaso". Una cosa es clara: "siquiera" es adverbio en esa oración, y significaría "al menos" o "tan solo". No es conjunción porque no introduce ninguna subordinada. Veamos las acepciones de "siquiera" en DLE:

> 1. conj. conc. aunque. Hazme este favor, siquiera sea el último.
> 2. conj. distrib. ya. Siquiera venga, siquiera no venga.
> 3. adv. al menos (‖ aunque no sea otra cosa). Deme usted media paga siquiera.
> 4. adv. Tan solo. U. en contextos negativos o irreales. No tengo un euro siquiera.

En cuanto a la subordinada, es una sustantiva de sujeto que aparece después del predicado porque, además de ser muy extensa, [en su correcto contexto](https://elpais.com/diario/2009/11/01/opinion/1257030004_850215.html) la oración es interrogativa:

> Si esto es así, resulta que las mujeres vivimos más, no por estar ociosas, sino por mantenernos más activas, por tener intereses más amplios y variados, por forzar a nuestro cerebro (**¿será siquiera verdad que, como pretenden algunos, el tamaño del cerebro se relacione con la inteligencia?**, tendré que preguntárselo a Acarín) a seguir funcionando a buena marcha.

Para constatar que es sujeto, podemos reemplazar la subordinada por un pronombre:

- ¿Será **esto** verdad?

En afirmativo, el sujeto podría aparecer delante del predicado, lo que nos permite descartar que modifique al sustantivo "verdad":

- Que el tamaño del cerebro se relaciona con la inteligencia es verdad / no es verdad.

Nota: El comentario (2) revela cierta confusión entre el sujeto de la subordinada y el sujeto de la oración en su conjunto. La frase nominal "el tamaño del cerebro" es sujeto de la subordinada, cuyo predicado es "se relacione con la inteligencia". A su vez, toda la proposición subordinada introducida por la conjunción "que" es sujeto de la oración que la incluye.